# Файлы создаются от root пользователя

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Почему при создании файлов в томе(`volumes`) из контейнера, они получают права от root пользователя?

Например: если мое приложение/скрипт генерирует логи или устанавливает зависимости программой из контейнера, то все файлы создается от root'а контейнера.

docker-контейнеры создаются/запускаются от имени обычного пользователя `user1` который находится в группе `docker`, т.е. без sudo

Из за этого, на хост машине, приходится постоянно писать `sudo chown my_user:host_users my_file`, чтобы дать "не root" пользователю возможность читать/редактировать файлы.

Существует ли возможность изменить это? Если - да, то как это делается в docker-compose?

Comment: а какая разница, изолирован ли хоть как-то запускаемый процесс или не изолирован? работает-то этот процесс от имени пользователя root. было бы странно, если бы было как-то по-другому.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, дело не процессе а файлах которые он создает в общих с хост машиной томах. Все файлы создаются от root'а контейнера, а мне нужно чтобы они создавались от пользователя хост машины. Я же не могу вечно набирать sudo chown

Comment: судя по употребляемым вами терминам, у вас наличествует некоторое недопонимание общей картины. в частности: не «от root'а контейнера», а просто «от root-а». то, что процесс изолирован (в просторечии — «запущен в контейнере»), ничего не меняет в этом отношении.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, docker- контейнер на хост машине запускается от обычно пользователя user1, user1 находится в группе docker т.е. когда я создаю/запускаю контейнер то делаю это без sudo. Внутри контейнера, все процессы работают от своего внутреннего root.  Когда например apache создает лог в томе,  то в контейнере и на хост машине у него владелец root

Comment: @XYZ `user1` лишь отдаёт команду Docker-демону запустить контейнер. А внутри контейнера процесс работает от рута и в создаваемых файлах указывается `uid` рута. Отсюда и ваши приключения. И [не только ваши](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259).

Comment: @D-side, да вы правы - причина в UID

Answer (score 1):

Права на файл назначаются того пользователя, от чьего имени файл создан. Если ваше приложение/сервис работают от `root` пользователя, то и все файлы, которые оно создает, будут от него же.

Чтобы этого избежать, приложение/сервис нужно запускать не от рута, а от обычного пользователя.

Comment: Контейнеры запускаются от обычного пользователя. Обновил вопрос

Comment: А от какого пользователя работает сервис докера

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов, сервис работает от пользователя user1. D-side выше дал верную наводку, осталось разобраться с конфигурацией UID и GID в docker-compose

Comment: @XYZ я сомневаюсь, что их можно настроить на уровне выше докерфайлов отдельных образов (на уровне compose, в частности).

Comment: Я думаю можно параметрами монтирования поиграть, чтоб на уровне ФС эти файлы стали пользовательскими.

а еще хорошей будет идея внутри докер контейнера создать пользователя и запускать прогу от него